# In Javascript how do I divide a multidimensional array by another array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, divide

I am missing something rather basic in my code but I cannot see it.  I need to normalize my matrix (array of arrays) by the row sum and/or column sum.

So a matrix of

```
matrix =[
[1, 2, 3, 10],
[4, 5, 6, 11],
[7, 8, 9, 12]
];
```

For a row normalization, this would result in every element in the first row / sum of row (e.g. 1/16, 2/16, 3/16, and 10/16). So my row normalized array would be

```
normalizedmatrix =[
[0.0625,        0.125,          0.1875,         0.625],
[0.153846154,   0.192307692,    0.230769231,    0.423076923],
[0.194444444,   0.222222222,    0.25,           0.333333333]
];
```

The rowSum function works as does the colSum.  However, the normalize function does not.  I cannot figure out why.

```
function rowSum(myMatrix) {
myTotal = [];
for (row = 0; row < myMatrix.length; row++) {
    myTotal[row] = myMatrix[row].reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
}
return myTotal;
}

function colSum(myMatrix) {
myTotal = [];
for (col = 0; col < myMatrix[0].length; col++) {
    myTotal[col] = myMatrix.map(function (v) {
        return v[col]
    }).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    });
}
return myTotal;
}

function normalize(myMatrix) {
myNormal = [];
myRowSums = rowSum(myMatrix);
//myColSums = colSum(myMatrix);

for (row = 0; row < myMatrix.length; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < myMatrix[0].length; col++) {
        myNormal[row][col] = myMatrix[row][col] / myRowSums[row]; // for row normalize
        // myNormal[row][col] = myMatrix /myColSums[col]; // for column normalize   
    }
}
return myNormal;
}

var matrix = [
[1, 2, 3, 10],
[4, 5, 6, 11],
[7, 8, 9, 12]
];

var rsum = rowSum(matrix);
var csum = colSum(matrix);
var normalsum = normalize(matrix);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of error message you're getting for your normalize function, but what I ran into was the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

This error occurs due to your declaration of `myNormal = []`. If you play around with this in DevTools, you'll see that the following will produce the error above:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0][0] = 1; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set Property '0' of undefined
```

This is because you are trying to access a value contained within a value that doesn't exist yet. In the above example, we could easily just do `arr[0] = 1` and everything would be fine. However, the statement `arr[0][0]` first tries to access the value located at `arr[0]` and then access its property `0`. Since that value does not exist, we get the above error. This is the situation that's occurring when you first try to set a value in your `myNormal` array.

One way we can fix this is by pre populating your `myNormal` array to match the dimensions of your input matrix.

For example:

```
// Create an empty matrix of size row x col
function emptyMatrix(row, col) {
   // The idea here is to build an Array of size "row", and then we will map
   // over each row and build an Array of size "col".
   var rows = Array.apply(null, Array(row));

   return rows.map(function () {
     return Array(col);
   });
}
```

Above, we have our methods that will build an empty array matrix for the given dimensions. We can use it to fix the `normalize` function by doing the following:

```
function normalize(myMatrix) {
    var numRows = myMatrix.length,
        numCols = myMatrix[0].length,
        myNormal = emptyMatrix(numRows, numCols),
        myRowSums = rowSum(myMatrix),
        // myColSums = colSum(myMatrix);
        row,
        col;

    for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
            myNormal[row][col] = myMatrix[row][col] / myRowSums[row];
            // myNormal[row][col] = myMatrix[row][col] / myColSums[col]; // for column normalize 
        }
    }

    return myNormal;
}
```

Hope this helps!